# How to avoid multiple for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dataframe "nsd" that has 175180 rows and 301 columns. My first 6 columns are filled with data and after that columns in (2k+1) [k>=5] are filled and rest are null. The null columns will be filled based on the values in columns that will get filled with the for loop running.

Since, it will be an element wise comparison for each column, I am using two for loops, the inner one to run through all the columns and the outer one to run through all the rows. This is taking like infinite time to run. How can I optimise this?

I tried removing the outer for loop and the j elements from my code, but then it just compares vector of length 1 and I am not able to do element wise comparison. Following is my code :

```
for (j in 1:175180) {
    for (i in 6:(ncol(nsd)-2)) {
       if ((i-1)%%5==0) {nsd[j,i]<-nsd[j,i]}
       else if ((i-2)%%5==0) {nsd[j,i]<-nsd[j,i-1]}
       else if ( (i-3)%%5==0 & nsd[j,i-1]>0  &  nsd[j,i-1] >= nsd[j,i-3] ) {nsd[j,i] <- nsd[j,i-1] - nsd[j,i-3]}
       else if ((i-3)%%5==0 & nsd[j,i-1]>=0  &  nsd[j,i-1]<nsd[j,i-3]) {nsd[j,i]<- 0}
       else if ((i-4)%%5==0 & nsd[j,i+2]>=(nsd[j,i-1]+nsd[j,i-4])) {nsd[j,i]<- nsd[j,i-1]+nsd[j,i-4]}
       else if ((i-4)%%5==0 & nsd[j,i+2]<(nsd[j,i-1]+nsd[j,i-4])) {nsd[j,i]<- nsd[j,i+2]}
       else if ((i-5)%%5==0 & (nsd[j,i-2] + nsd[j,i-5]) > nsd[j, i-1]) {nsd[j,i]<- nsd[j,i-2] + nsd[j,i-5] - nsd[j, i-1] }
       else if ((i-5)%%5==0 & (nsd[j,i-2] + nsd[j,i-5]) <= nsd[j, i-1]) {nsd[j,i]<- 0 }
   }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first make an identifier of the columns like so:

```
cols <- seq(6 ,(ncol(nsd)-2))
set1 <- which(cols %% 5 == 0)
```

Then use this to index your `data.frame` and perform the operations:

```
nsd[,cols[set1]] <- nsd[,cols[set1]-1]
```

etc...

Using this concept you should be able to vectorize all of your operations.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't run the operation on an entire set. E.g.

Comment: set1 <- which(cols %% 5 == 0)
would apply to columns 10,15,20 etc., but before filling columns 10, I would need to fill column 9 by its unique logic. Similarly, before filling column 9, I would have to fill column 8.

Comment: presumably, some column needs to be filled first... so vectorize that part and work backwards. Your example is not very easy to understand.